# Windows 8 change Border Padding

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8-preview, windows-8, desktop-customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reduce the size of the titlebar and window border padding on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012?](https://superuser.com/questions/461982/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-the-titlebar-and-window-border-padding-on-windows-8)

In Windows 7 was a "Advanced appearance settings" where the **border padding** (ugly fat border weight/size around every window) could be reduced. .

In Windows 8 this option has disappeared. So do I need to tweak the registry? But where?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found the solution. Go to the registry (**Win+R**) and run **regedit**.

Then go here:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics

And set the following values to 0:

```
BorderWidth = 0
PaddedBorderWidth = 0
```

Originally they contained the values -15 and -60.

[See this post for some more customizations.](https://superuser.com/questions/461982/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-the-titlebar-and-window-border-padding-on-windows-8)

My windows explorer now looks much nicer and more professional:
[image]