# How do I increase the size of the titlebar and window border padding on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, desktop-customization

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/461982/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-the-titlebar-and-window-border-padding-on-windows-8) talks about changing the Titlebar and Window Border Padding so that it is smaller. What if I want it back to its original size?

[image: Control Panel\Display]

As seen in the picture above, I cannot change it from the Display options in the Control Panel.

Comment: That is unusual. I have a choice between 6-24 on Windows 8.1 on a Retina MacBook Pro. Of course I have many many more scaling sizes available to me, from 100% to 200% which is pretty important since the native resolution is 2880x1800 and the display is only 15 inches.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you changed your default font for the title bars away from Segoe.  Tsk, tsk!  That is not the micro$oft way!

If you change the font back to Segoe, your different sizes will return, I promise.
This looks like a windows 8.0 bug.

I had this happen to me as well, it turns out that the process of getting rid of Segoe in favor of Tahoma (which I've done many times on many Win7 and Win8 systems), may have been the culprit.

Comment: How do I change the font?