# Changing the Title Bar style on Windows 10 applications

Tags: windows-10, desktop, desktop-customization, window-manager, uwp

Applications in Windows 10 have a title bar in one of two styles.

The style that is present for "normal" desktop applications:
[image: normal application title bar]

And the style that appears in UWP applications:
[image]

I'm wondering if it is somehow possible to change an attribute of a running application, or change some registry key, like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/952395/how-to-change-window-title-bar-size-in-windows-10), to make it so that my "normal" desktop applications automatically have the new updated UWP title bar. I know it's possible to create / compile a new application with the updated title bar, but **is it possible to force an older application to have the new UWP titlebar without recompiling it?**

*(A good answer for this question will demonstrate how to do so or include a technical explanation why this isn't possible.)*

Comment: You can actually answer the question youself if you research what UWP actually is. It is far more than just the way an application looks. It is a whole framework, similarly as .net, but designed to create an app that can be integrated with the Windows Store, and can run on ARM, such that it works on a mobile phone OR desktop. So no, you can't just recompile it. You have to invest a lot of effort if you want to go this route.

Comment: @LPChip I am familiar with what UWP is, but I've also seen non-UWP applications use the UWP titlebar, thus the origin of my question.

Comment: An application is free to change its appearance. That doesn't mean it is using the UWP framework, but it is also possible they actually DO use the UWP framework and thus are UWP apps.