# Default Registry Values for WindowMetrics in Windows 10

Tags: windows-registry, windows-10

I followed the guide [here](https://superuser.com/questions/461982/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-the-titlebar-and-window-border-padding-on-windows-8) to change the window padding in Windows 10, but forgot to create a backup of those registry keys, and now want to revert the change. Is there a way to see the default, preset values for registry keys, specifically the ones under:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`

Comment: On another W10 pc export the WindowMetrics key using regedit, then merge it into the problem PC.

Comment: I found the solution I was looking for. See my posted answer.

Comment: Those settings are different from my install of W10, glad you solved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default values for the changed values in WindowMetrics are below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]

"CaptionHeight"="-330"
"CaptionWidth"="-330"
"CaptionFont"=hex:f4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"ScrollWidth"="-255"
"ScrollHeight"="-255"
"PaddedBorderWidth"="-60"
```

from [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f48kd/windows_10_tips_and_tricks/ctxf2nn).

Answer (score 8):

On another W10 pc export the WindowMetrics key using regedit, then merge it into the problem PC

or copy the text below into a text file and save, then rename the extension .txt to .reg, the right click on it and select merge.

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]

"IconTitleWrap"="1"

"Shell Icon Size"="32"

"BorderWidth"="-12"

"CaptionFont"=hex:f1,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"CaptionHeight"="-336"

"CaptionWidth"="-336"

"IconFont"=hex:f1,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"MenuFont"=hex:f1,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"MenuHeight"="-288"

"MenuWidth"="-288"

"MessageFont"=hex:f1,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"ScrollHeight"="-252"

"ScrollWidth"="-252"

"SmCaptionFont"=hex:f1,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,\
  00,00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"SmCaptionHeight"="-336"

"SmCaptionWidth"="-336"

"StatusFont"=hex:f1,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,05,00,53,00,65,00,67,00,6f,00,65,00,20,00,55,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"AppliedDPI"=dword:00000078

"PaddedBorderWidth"="-60"

"IconSpacing"="-1125"

"IconVerticalSpacing"="-1125"

"MinAnimate"="1"
```