# Windows 10 multi-tasking snap not resizing windows to fill the screen

Tags: windows-10

Information:

- Resolution: 1680 x 1050
- Graphics model & driver: Nvidia Quadro K420
- Monitor model: DELL 3007WFPHC
- Connection type: DVI

This is the information for my current setup, but I am having the same issue on my Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon Gen7 that has no monitor, and is running 1920x1080 resolution.

I am running Windows 10 and use the window snapping feature quite often by holding down the windows key and using the arrow keys. However, an issue I consistently run into is when I snap a window to the left or right side of the screen, it almost always doesn't fill the window.

There was a similar question asked on Microsoft forums (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/multi-tasking-snap-not-resizing-windows-to-fill/50a7acfe-3c26-4586-81aa-1355c1015766) but the only response by a technician was to make sure the `When I snap a window, automatically size it to fill available space` setting is enabled, which I do have enabled.

[image]

---

Here are additional images from own PC of the behavior. You can see the top of the browser literally being cutoff from the monitor display in the first picture.

**Not Fully Snapped**
[image: Not fully snapped]

**Fully Snapped**
[image: Fully snapped]

Comment: probably there are some app that lays a transparent bar on top of the desktop, or there are some issues with the graphics driver?

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and drag the bullseye icon over the empty space. This will find the process whose window is taking up this space. If that process is `explorer.exe`, this means the desktop, so that space is truly empty and snap isn't working correctly.

Comment: Snapping for me DOES fill the whole area, however I DO still get the resize-arrow-cursor at the top & is cut off just like yours so this is normal. Is the screenshot from your PC or a random one on the internet? I see the black bar at top, however since your resize-arrow-cursor is getting cut off I am wondering if its been edited into the photo? Maybe your monitor settings need to be adjusted, but even if YOU saw black bar at top a screenshot wouldn't capture that. Please provide another screenshot AFTER you adjust one of the snapped windows to be maximum height

Comment: Can you update question with your: 1)Resolution. 2)Graphics model & driver . 3)Monitor model & connection type (VGA, DVI, HDMI, DP)

Comment: @gregg I added additional images of my PC. You can see the browser is being cutoff at the top of the monitor. It appears to be trying to resize to resolution larger than the monitor and then after snapping the window again resizes to the correct resolution.

Comment: @AlexF Indeed I'm seeing that. Can you go to Settings, System, Multitasking then:
1)uncheck 'When I snap a window, automatically size it to fill available space'. 2)uncheck 'When I resize a snapped window...' 3)Turn off Snap windows. 4)Reboot. 5)Re-enable those settings. 6)Cross your fingers it did some magic. If that doesn't work I'd look at updating your video drivers & trying to login to the PC as another user to note if it happens, various preferences are user-specific

Comment: Could you do the test in my above comment, for more information?

Comment: @harrymc I tested your solution and it's giving me explorer.exe. It's strange too because I have the same issue on my laptop which is a completely different display and PC model, but both are running the latest Windows 10 build

Comment: @AlexF if it's happening on your laptop & another PC sadly the common denominator is you. 1)Do you have any custom Windows GUI modification tools installed (ie. stardock, etc.)? 2)Are you using the Windows beta build/update channels? 3)Have you checked the Nvidia Control Panel? 4)Have you updated those drivers?

Comment: Use `regedit` to navigate to registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`. Check if your values are very different from in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/954408/default-registry-values-for-windowmetrics-in-windows-10). If you wish to experiment, export first the `WindowMetrics` key to a file as backup. Or you could take a screenshot and add it to your post for us to take a look. Sometimes setting `PaddedBorderWidth` to `0` helps.

Comment: Id troubleshoot by using raw drivers. IE: removing GPU Tool/settings app. (IE: Nvideo settings or Radeon Settings etc.)

Comment: @AlexF: Any answer to my last comment?

Comment: @harrymc setting the `PaddedBorderWidth` and `BorderWidth` to 0 solved the issue for me. If you'd like to post an answer I'd be happy to award you the bounty.

Comment: Answer was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows metrics for displaying graphic windows can be found under the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`.

The problem here was solved by setting `PaddedBorderWidth` and `BorderWidth` to zero (0).

The units for these values are in [twips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip) and may
contain as value any negative number up to 0.
A value of 0 will produce no padding, while for example a value of -300 will produce
a very fat border.
`PaddedBorderWidth` should be larger or equal to `BorderWidth`.

The limits are:

- `BorderWidth` - valid values are 0 to -750
- `PaddedBorderWidth` - valid values are 0 to -1600

[image]