# Windows 10 strange behavior of title bar

Tags: windows-10, resolution, scaling, title-bar

I'm facing strange issue on Windows 10. Same application behaves different on same windows version - the difference is seen at title bar appearance:

[image]

Above is **normal**, expected (at least by me) behavior - all three buttons are in the right corner, the application logo and title in the top-left. Under certain circumstances (which I can't find and thus need your help) the same application title bar looks like this:

[image]

The three buttons take all the length of title bar and centered in it, title bar's height is 30 pixels longer, application logo is top-right and application title disappears at all.

The question is what windows 10 setting(if any) causes such difference for same application? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you customized title & fonts?

Comment: I don't know, this came from user. That is exactly the question - what customization can cause such appearance ?

Comment: 1)DPI scaling... ( it looks so he set 125% instead of normal 100%)
2) Custom font size (as i said earlier)

Comment: both things are just making buttons greater but how did the user managed to break their layout ? they are actually centered within title bar

Comment: Then you have to try out this... https://superuser.com/questions/461982/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-the-titlebar-and-window-border-padding-on-windows-8

Comment: Like @Reborn said, it's probably caused by DPI scaling or custom element sizes in the Windows Personalization section.  One thing to note is, you have to log off, log back in for it to take effect completely.  User sees "You must log out" message, user says "Pfft!" and closes it, and then different apps display differently in confusing ways.  Have the user log out and back in.

Comment: Has the user installed any software from [Stardock Corporation](http://www.stardock.com/products/) such as WindowBlinds or Object Desktop?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage at some point you are right, but not completely.

Comment: was this PC installed with mote than one monitor?

Comment: Tell us more about the computer's display setup. How many displays? Is this a laptop? Is it on a dock? Also, does the problem go away (at least temporarily) if you sign out and then back into the account and run the application again?

Comment: Try creating a new user account on the device and tell us if the unwanted behavior persists in that account.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this Registry tweak](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-reduce-title-bar-height-and-size-of-window-buttons-in-windows-10/) from winaero.com:

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and in the box that pops ups type `regedit`.

   **Note:** Extreme caution is advised when using the Registry Editor.
2. Once you are in Registry Editor go to the key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
   ```
3. Click on the string value named **CaptionHeight** and set its value using the following formula:

   ```
   -15 * The desired amount of height you want
   ```

   For example, if you want to set the bar height to 18 pixels you would change it to `-15*18 = -270`.

   [image]
4. Sign out and then back into your account to make the change take effect.

You could also try Winaero Tweaker.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We always welcome the contributions from our community members, but can you please cite the source for your proposed solution?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: This does not explain why the same application is showing differently on different occasions.

Comment: Source - http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-reduce-title-bar-height-and-size-of-window-buttons-in-windows-10/                                                                       I was having the same problem but when I edited that value it stopped doing it. I honestly have no idea what caused it. Im just rying to fix the problem.